# How to properly terminate a pthread?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a tcp echo server that creates a pthread for each client that connects to it. For each connection, I have a variable `nbOfClients` that increments.
When a client closes its connection, I detect it and decrease the number of clients. However the server keeps thinking that the client it alive and keeps on trying to read/write from the socket. I guessed that it was because of the thread that created the client and I tries to kill the thread with `pthread_cancel` all to non avail.
I want to kill the pthread associated to a certain client that closes its connection.
How can I go about it?

Here's my code :

```
static int nbOfClients = 0;

static  pthread_t tid;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int bytes_to_read, arg, listen_sd, new_conn, sockfd, client_len, port;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client_addr;
    char *bp, buf[BUFLEN];
    ssize_t n;


    sockfd = 0;

    switch(argc) {
        case 1:
          port = SERVER_TCP_PORT;   // Use the default port
          break;
        case 2:
          port = atoi(argv[1]); // Get user specified port
          break;
        default:
          fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [port]\n", argv[0]);
          exit(1);
    }

    // Create a stream socket
    if ((listen_sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
        error("Cannot Create Socket!");

    // set SO_REUSEADDR so port can be resused imemediately after exit, i.e., after CTRL-c
    arg = 1;
    if (setsockopt (listen_sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &arg, sizeof(arg)) == -1)
        error("setsockopt");

    // Bind an address to the socket
    bzero((char *)&server, sizeof(server));
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // Accept connections from any client

    if (bind(listen_sd, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == -1)
        error("bind error");

    listen(listen_sd, MAX_CONNECTIONS); ///put a define constant indicating the maximum number of clients #define NB_CLIENTS 3

    while (TRUE) {
        client_len = sizeof(client_addr);
        if ((new_conn = accept(listen_sd, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, (socklen_t *)&client_len)) == -1)
          error("accept error");

        if(new_conn > 0) {
            if(nbOfClients < MAX_CONNECTIONS) {
                printf("just here\n");
                printf(">> Initializing remote address: %s\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr));
                nbOfClients++;


                fclose(fp);

                printf("Connections to date: %u \n",nbOfClients);

                printf("make thread\n");
                pthread_create(&tid,NULL,&echo, (void *)new_conn);
                printf("had thread\n");
            }
            else {
                printf("connection limit reached\n");
                if(send(new_conn, "Server full!\n", 13, 0) == -1)
                    perror("send");
                close(new_conn);
            }
        }
    }

    return(0);
}

void * echo(void *arg) {
    char buf[BUFSIZE]; /* message buffer */
    int n, i = 0;

    bzero(buf, BUFSIZE);
    if(send((int)arg, "Welcome!!\n", 20, 0) == -1)
        perror("send");

    detect_closed_connection(arg);

    while(TRUE) {
        n = read((int)arg, buf, BUFSIZE);

        /**read: read input string from the client*/
        if(n < 0) {
            perror("error reading from socket");
        }

        printf("Server received from client, %d bytes: %s\n", n, buf);

        /**write: echo the input string in UPPERCASE back to the client*/

        int len = strlen(buf);
        for(i = 0; buf[i]; i++)
            buf[i] = toupper(buf[i]);

        n = write((int)arg, buf, len);
        if(n < 0) {
            error("ERROR writing to socket");
        }
    }
}

void detect_closed_connection(void * listenSocket) {
    struct pollfd pfd;
    pfd.fd = (int)listenSocket;
    pfd.events = POLLIN | POLLHUP | POLLRDNORM;
    pfd.revents = 0;
    while(pfd.revents == 0) {
        if(poll(&pfd, 1, 100) > 0) {
            // if result > 0, this means that there is either data available on the
            // socket, or the socket has been closed
            char buffer[32];
            if (recv((int)listenSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), MSG_PEEK | MSG_DONTWAIT) == 0) {
                // if recv returns zero, that means the connection has been closed:

                nbOfClients--;
                pthread_cancel(tid);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: "*When a client closes its connection, I detect it and decrease the number of clients.*" Where do you do this, dispite **before** entering the endless echo-loop?

Comment: I detect it in the endless echo loop. detect_closed_connection(arg); Does it mean that I should detect a closed connection before entering the loop? I'm not ure if putting it in the main function just after creating the thread would function properly

Comment: "*I detect it in the endless echo loop.*" No you don't, you call `detect_closed_connection(arg);` **before** `while(TRUE`) which is the head of the endless loop. The thread never ever goes before this line anymore.

Comment: Mea culpa. You're right. Corrected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check `read()` for returning `0` in the thread servering the client, as `read()` returns `0` in case the peer (client here) closed the connection.

After this line

```
n = read((int)arg, buf, BUFSIZE);
```

add

```
if (0 == n)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "The client closed the connection.\n");
  break;
}
```

Just before the thread function leave you could add the statement to decrement the number of running threads.

---

Also **be aware that `nbOfClients` is accessed concurently** by all the "client"-threads as well as by the main thread, so accessing it shall be protected, for example by using a mutex.

---

There is another issues, as the call to `strlen()` on the buffer read expects the buffer to be `0`-terminate, which does not necessarily needs ot be the case, even if you sent `0`-terminated "strings". `read()` might very well return the "string" the client sent in more then one part. So loop around `read()` until the `0`-terminator had been received.

---

Do not make the thread end itself by calling `pthread_cancel()`, use `pthread_exit()` instead.

Comment: Yeah great point! I didn't think about the mutex on the nbOfClients. I should definetely protect the access on nbOfClients About the read, that explains a lot about why the server keeps on returning parts of the previous words the client sent. Thanks for he explanation

Comment: @mkab: My advise to loop around `read()` applies to `write()` as well. Read the man-pages carefully on what these functions return if called on sockets. This also applies to `recv()` and `send()`.

Comment: If I understand well, in order to read and write data from the sockets using `read()` and `write()`, I should loop through the buffer until I encounter the `'\0'` character? Does the same apply to `recv()` and `send()`?

Comment: @mkab: Please see my updated answer on how to have a thread end itself.

Comment: Ok I understand about using `pthread_exit()`. Seems a lot safer. Can you please check my last question about `read()`, `write()`, `recv()` and `send()`?

Comment: @mkab: Please do as advised in my comments, this includes reading the according man-pages. And if you **really** want to get into this read this book: http://www.amazon.de/Unix-Network-Programming/dp/8120307496/ It also has good examples. Here the newer editions;: http://www.amazon.de/Network-Programming-Volum-Prentice-engl/dp/013490012X and her http://www.amazon.de/Unix-Network-Programming-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0131411551

Comment: Try your self to find a solution and if it does not work or specific problem arouse, come back here with a specific question showing us what you did so far, ok? :-)